# average of attribute in a list of objects

Tags: python, list, attributes, average

I have a list of user's. Each user will have a `waitTime` attribute. How do I get the average `waitTime` for all users in the list? The code below will probably work, but I'm guessing that there is a better way to do it.

```
sum = 0
for user in self.done:
    sum += user.waitTime 
sum/len(self.done)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the builtin `sum` function combined with a generator expression for this.

```
sum(user.waitTime for user in self.done)/float(len(self.done))
```

The `float` is only necessary in python2.x and only if all the `user.waitTime` objects are integers.

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator expression and `sum` for the sum:

```
sum(user.waitTime for user in self.done) / float(len(self.done))
```

If the times are integers, you need to convert the result from `len()`  into float, otherwise you get integer division, i.e. truncating in Python 2.